# android development - using android.os.Handler for inter class communication

Tags: android, architecture

One of the struggles I have as android development newbie is that my classes have the tendency to get quite extensive with all the inner classes etc for gui listener and so on. So I came up with one solution to decompose my classes which I would like to hear some feedback form the android experts around.

To put it into an example. I dont want to define all the dialogs a particular Activity has within the same class (there is a series of Dialogs taking place in that activity) 
So I implemented a DialogManager class to define and hold all the potential Dialogs, hand over a handler instance from the Activity to this DialogManager and use it to inform the Activity about what gui events have happened.

Here a snippet of this DialogManager class, mHandler is the handler which calls back to the Activity

```
mDownloadDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

mDownloadDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                      

                        mDownloadDialog.dismiss();

                        Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                        message.arg1 = DOWNLOAD_DIALOG;
                        message.arg2 = AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE;
                        message.sendToTarget();
                    }
                });
```

So this works and I am happy with the more organized source code now but I wonder if the Handler class is the proper way to do this or if this is a bit of an overkill and there are some better ways to achieve the same result which are recommended.

EDIT:
As pointed out by boulder

**handler messages aren't executed immediately**

So with this in mind using Handler is not the proper way to go.

Next idea would be as simple as defining in the given example an Interface

```
public interface DialogEventReceiverInterface { 
public void dialogEvent(int dialog,int button);
}
```

implementing that interface in the Activity, hand the activity over to the DialogManager and call dialogEvent in the case an event takes place. Pretty straight forward it seems to me now ...

Comment: Since handler messages aren't executed immediately but added to task queue instead, you can encounter situations when two subsequent "close" messages are sent for example. This can happen if user make two fast clicks on Cancel button

Comment: Even if this will not cause any problem you are forced to think about possible problems then writing you code and this is not good

Comment: Thank you a lot _boulder_, this sounds like a killer argument against this approach. I guess I should better go for the Interface solution briefly mentioned in my question. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate that you're not necessarily specifically asking about tidying up the clutter associated with `Dialog`s, but rather the `Dialog` code you show is just an illustration of a wider problem I think you're asking for a design pattern to solve.

However, focusing on your specific example of `Dialog`s, the Android APIs now already provide a much cleaner solution for this in the form of `Fragment`s and specifically `DialogFragment`. Using the `Fragment` classes is a much cleaner way of doing things because you generally define your `DialogFragment`s in separate class files. The Android API documentation contains very good guidelines about how to handle communication between the `DialogFragment`s and parent `Activity`.

Before I switched to using `Fragment`s for everything, I too ended up with lots of `Dialog`s being created within `Activity` classes and I tried various design patterns with dialog managers, etc. However, the `Fragment` approach is so much cleaner in my opinion.

Compatibility with earlier Android versions is no problem because you can use the V4 support package.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I actually havent really looked into Fragments yet but what you mention sounds very promising. For my current app (my first one) I will stick to this non fragment approach yet your answer definitely inspires me to go for fragments asap. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way you are right, my whole approach right now is looking for the design patterns/best practices within the android framework. The android documentation is quite good for that yet I still miss a comprehensive book/resource on that

Answer (score 1):

This may not be 100% what you are looking for, but it may address the issues that you are having with your Android apps.

Frequently I end up with a lot of inner class listeners and such when handling a lot of UI events, another option is publish-subscribe.  Where you publish events and objects subscribe to particular events.  In Android Google has this sweet set of libraries they use called `Guava` that has a TON of great things.  One of which is `EventBus` that makes this a little easier.

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained

They have some nice examples in there and walk you through it.  It's a big change and a different way of thinking through your UI, so I wouldn't just jump in without investigating.  Make sure it's right for your project.

EventBus is cool, and there is a lot of great functionality in the `Guava` library.

Comment: Thanks xbakesx, looks like an awesome library.. For now I go for the interface solution I just added to my initial question (if nobody refutes that idea either) yet for more complex scenarios guava will be in the back of my mind to look into. Thanks